# Verifying a RSASSA-PSS signed in Java using BouncyCastle provider

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, bouncycastle, x509

I'm very new to certificate concept and I would like to know how to verify signature of a certificate with RSASSA-PSS algorithm (OID - 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10).

```
package com.learn.package.certificates;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class VerifyCertificate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        X509Certificate clientCert = ...;
        X509Certificate caCert = ...; 
        c1.verify(c2.getPublicKey(), "BC");
    }
}
```

While running I'm getting this error..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:449)
    at com.learn.package.certificates.VerifyCertificate.main(VerifyCertificate.java:33)
```

I'm able to verify those certificates from command line via openssl using the command

```
op verify -CAfile cacert.pem clientcert.pem
>> clientcert.pem: OK
```

I might not sure what I'm missing (may be something trivial), but can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure c1 has been issued by c2? Maybe there's an intermediate entity (cacert.pem could contain several certificates)

Comment: @pedrofb Yes, I'm sure because I'm able to verify in command line using openssl..

Comment: Could you post the certificates (in PEM format) and BC version in the question? You didn't switch the certificates? Note that you didn't provide us the code as the names are obviously not the same (c1/c2 and clientCert/caCert).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes elaborated my problem in my latest post here - http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Using-RSASSA-PSS-signature-algorithm-to-verify-a-certificate-in-Java-td4658632.html#a4658690.

Comment: Is there an update on how this can be solved ?